# How to store two different array's in code igniter cart?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, cart

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => round
            [1] => EX
            [2] => D
            [3] => 3.6
            [4] => IF
            [5] => IGI
            [6] => G
            [7] => G
            [8] => id01
            [9] => FNT
            [10] => 0.8
            [11] => 47
            [12] => xy01
            [13] => india
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => round
            [1] => EX
            [2] => D
            [3] => 3.6
            [4] => IF
            [5] => IGI
            [6] => G
            [7] => G
            [8] => id01
            [9] => FNT
            [10] => 0.8
            [11] => 47
            [12] => xy01
            [13] => india
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => 150
    [1] => 150
)
```

This Two Array's I Got When I Click Update Cart Button In Codeigniter Cart...
In This Two Arrays First Array Is Description About Two Different Product And Second Array Is The Price Of That Two Products...First Price Is For First Product And Second Price Is For Second Product...

now i want to store this two products in cart one by one...i mean at first, first product is stored in cart with respective price and then second product with price..

And i want to store this array in particular array index..

This is the index of the array..

```
shape
cut
color
carat
clarity
lab
polish
symmetry
stone_id
fluorescence
lwratio
depth
cert_no
location
price
```

First Product with price store in this array and then in cart...likewise second..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a single array with description & price then go with below code...

```
$final_array=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($description_array);$i++)
{
  $final_description=$description_array[$i];
  array_push($final_description,$price_array[$i]); //here we push the price into description array
  array_push($final_array,$final_description);
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5727/array-iteration#t=201701161237085819865

Answer (score 1):

First, add the price to the first array. Then use `array_combine()` to apply the index as keys - Something like-

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => &$val) {
  $val[] = $array2[$key];
  //$index is array of indexes mentioned.
  $newArr[] = array_combine($index, $val);
}

var_dump($newArr);
```